# Passing parameter to bash cgi script via a HTML form

Tags: html, forms, bash, cgi

As you see I have a simple drop-down and based on the selection I call certain CGI scripts on linux host named server01.  I need to pass a parameter to whichuser.cgi script. I tried just to put in the parameter after the script name and also tried to put it in the quote ; to no avail. Can this be done in the format I'm doing? Can you provide some direction?

```
<HTML>

<form name="form1" method="POST">
Select a page to visit: 
<select name="dd1" size=1>

<option value="http://server01/cgi-bin/adsusers.cgi">
server01
</option>

<option value="http://server01/cgi-bin/whichuser.cgi">
server02
</option>

</select>
<input type="button" 
 onClick=
 "location = 
  document.form1.dd1.options
  [document.form1.dd1.selectedIndex].value;" 
 value="GO">
</form>

</HTML>
```

Comment: This parameter, is it constant or do you need to get the value from the user? If constant, you could use `<input type="hidden" name="foo" value="bar">`. Since this is `method=POST`, the script won't look for parameters in the QUERY_STRING.

Comment: hi this value is constant, So basically if the value in the drop down  is equal server02  then i need the value server2 passed on to the script, if the value in the drop down is server01 , then I need to pass server01.

Comment: sounds like your html needs some javascript to submit the form with the wanted parameters

Comment: So I cannot pass a parameter using html ? Is that what you are saying there is no way to pass a parameter using html?

Comment: You can certainly pass a *static* value (or a user-entered value), but you need to value to be *dynamic*. HTML cannot do that.